# Google Adwords campaign is not receiving any traffic at all, despite raising my bid

Tags: google-ads

I have two sets of ads, one for search and one for display network only.

The search ads have had 2 impressions, no clicks, the daily budget is £15 and there are 94 keywords targeted, 75 are those recommended by Google's Opportunities.

The display network ads were getting clicks, 121 in total from 47,000 impressions. The daily spend was £7. No there are no impressions and no clicks, so I increased the daily budget to £25, still no new impressions.

Both are active and approved. I have no idea what has happened. Why as the former never had any impressions and why the latter has simply stopped working over night.

Bids are set to 'Focus on clicks, automatic bidding, no CPC bid limit'. But looking it says "auto £3.96".

They are high competition. The keyword planner suggests bids of 70p - which is much lower than I think its set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had Manual Payments on with no money in my account.

But after speaking with Google it turns out I had discovered a bug. Where by the fact you had no money in your account was only shown on the Billing page and not on any other page.

So I was completely unaware of the issue when attempting to fix the problem by changing my ad settings.